# How to create sockets which are not blocked by company networks?

Tags: java, android, sockets, telnet

I am able to create socket connection between my server and android device. I am able to send and receive data on the socket. But it gets blocked on some company networks. It connects to the server but I am not able to send/receive data on the socket connection. 
Is there some pattern in which I need to send data to the server so that it does not get blocked. I am sending data in plain text using python on the server side for socket server.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your socket. You should try using a port that is open. But this is impossible to know for every network out there.

Comment: I am able to create connection with the server so ports are not the problem. The problem is that I am not able to send data. Whatsapp and other services does that, so there must be a solution or I should say a correct form in which data could be sent

Comment: Whatsapp probably speaks RESTful over common port 80. So it should have no problems. What port do you use and what protocol?

Comment: I am also using port 80 and is a websocket protocol